# How to find the most common error code in web server access logs

Tags: bash, apache, http

How do I find the most common error code in web server access.log?

Comment: Filter out error codes, for instance with `grep -o` then count them using `sort | uniq -c`. The actual answer depends on your log format. Please give us a small sample of your `acess.log` that includes different errors and non-errors.

Comment: @Socowi The format of webserver access logs is pretty standard.

Comment: @Barmar The [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html) does not list *the* standard format. There is only the note that `LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common` is »*A typical configuration*«. If OP showed at least that little bit of effort no one had to waste time building solutions on assumptions.

Comment: @Socowi [Common Log Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Log_Format)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
cat /var/log/apache2/access_log | sed 's/\[.*\]//' | sort | uniq -c | awk '//{if($1>=5) print $0}' | sort -nr
```

The idea is to strip down things that change from line to line, like timestamps, or IP addresses, in order to aggregate the errors. In this case I've only stripped timestamps using `sed`, assuming they are enclosed in square brackets. So `sed 's/\[.*\]//'` will replace this `\[.*\]` with nothing.

So as an example, this line:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [03/Oct/2016:23:45:27 +0300] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
```

will become this:

```
127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
```

Then `sort` and `uniq -c` will aggregate the adjacent identical lines, and prepend the number of duplicates. 
So it will look something like this:

```
22 127.0.0.1 - -  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 1406
```

This means the following line (minus the stripped timestamp) has appeared 22 times in the log.

Then `awk '//{if($1>=5) print $0}'` will display only the duplicate lines that appeared 5 or more times, 5 being arbitrary. And then the final sort.

This was tested on OSX and Ubuntu.